# Angular, filter by key < number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to achieve the effect of running a piece of data through a filter that would check a key of .quanity of the object and return it if its less than 200.

So like

```
<md-item ng-repeat="item in displayed | filter:quantity < 200">
```

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `item.quantity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter method in your controller and have it assigned to the filter.

Something like this:

```
  $scope.filterQuantity = function(item){
     return item.quantity < 200;
  };
```

Html

```
<md-item ng-repeat="item in displayed | filter: filterQuantity">
```